# Circular Saw Throws Wood at End of Cut

Tags: circular-saw

I bought a circular saw recently. I noticed that sometimes as I finish a cut, the saw throws the free end of the board forward a couple of feet. Most of the time, the board just drops as expected, but every now and then, it gets projected. It doesn't seem like a huge deal, but I was curious to know if there is a technique to prevent this.

The wood I am cutting is SPF. I believe I've usually seen this happen when I am cutting off smaller pieces, from 2" to 12" in length. I am making crosscuts across boards that are 2" to 3" wide, and I make the cut in about 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Is this dimensional lumber? Or some kind of laminated wood like plywood/OSB? How much wood is at the end, getting cut off? Also how fast are you moving the saw through?

Comment: Also if you haven't yet, it's always good to watch a video or two on YouTube of someone using a tool if you are having issues with using it. I like this guy, personally (no affiliation) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jDfpl1_I904 (video is "circular saw 'pro' tips"). I think he also has a 'basics' video, too.

Comment: Updated the question with additional information to answer your questions. I am moving the saw somewhat slowly - perhaps I need to move it faster. Thanks.

Comment: 1-2 seconds for a cut is not 'slowly'. Faster than that is bad. Can you clarify if this is your meaning? And can you describe how the wood is positioned when you're cutting? (On the ground, sawhorses, offcut unsupported, etc?)

Comment: ... and can you tell us a little bit about your technique? Are you following a complete line, setting a square against the baseplate, ...?

Comment: Well, when I say 1-2 seconds, I mean the time between when the blade hits the wood and when it finishes the cut. And these are narrow pieces of wood (2" to 3"). But maybe I am still moving the saw too fast during the cut.

Comment: I am supporting the piece of wood on a table. The piece I am keeping is hanging freely off the end of the table, so that when I finish the cut, the piece I am keeping falls to the ground (or projects forward, as described in the question).

Comment: I am using a speed square against the baseplate to make the cut.

Comment: I have always seen/heard you want the discarded piece to fall and the 'kept' piece to be on the table/sawhorses. This could be your issue; the wood is bending and pinching as you get close to the end of the cut and because the longer piece (presumably) is unsupported, it has more momentum to shoot away.

Comment: To add to TylerH's comment, anytime wood contacts the actual saw blade body (aka a pinch) then this can cause kickback.  Wood should never touch the actual body of the saw blade because when you make a straight cut, the 'kerf' of the saw blade is clearing just enough space in the wood for the whole saw blade to slide through.  If the wood pinches the saw blade body, it is not going to be cut and rather the energy of the rotating blade will transfer to the wood and cause it to move--kickback.  This applies to almost any saw with a large saw body, including hand saws.

Comment: Adding above, jig saws and coping saws are *slight* exceptions to that rule because they have very small-bodied saws exactly to prevent pinching to a serious degree.  This is because those kinds of saws are designed for making curved cuts, where the saw blade body will inevitably make contact with wood.  As a good rule of thumb, you should ensure whatever cutting setup you have will not cause the wood to pinch the saw blade.  Just because it hasn't hurt you yet doesn't mean it's okay--if you don't understand this concept when working with a table saw, you can be seriously injured.

Comment: Finally, hand tools will not cause 'kickback' in the traditional sense of the word, but if you're using a handsaw and allow the wood to pinch the blade, you will have a very tough time cutting through the wood as the pinch will resist your attempt to saw through.  An easy way to tell if your saw blade is pinching is to check for paint smear.  Most saw blades are painted and if the wood pinches, it will smear that paint and deposit some of it onto the work piece.  If you use Diablo blades, your work piece will have red all over the cut line if your saw blade is pinching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learned this technique from my house-builder father from a young age: Do your cross cut (or any cut) normally but pause very near the end of the cut with the saw still running. Then focus on keeping the saw straight and zing the last bit. Use plenty of follow through as you shoot the saw away from the cut and the waste piece drops to the floor.